# How can I list the services in python and manage their performance?

Tags: python, service

How can I list all services (and its details-name,date, etc...) in linux via python code and how can I check whether a certain service works properly?

Is there a python library which enable working with services in linux?

thank you

Comment: well, not exactly, I have add another question here. I also looking for python library, and not using the shell.

Comment: @joe Then it becomes off-topic. At the moment I have closed it as dupe, If you prefer otherwise, I'll reopen it and it'll be closed as off-topic (which is bad)